# Getting Query Parameter from a URL which inturn has some URL with Query parameters

Tags: javascript, regex, url, query-string

I've the following URL

```
http://somesite/somepage.aspx
```

I pass a query parameter value which has another URL with query parameters like this.

http://somesite/somepage.aspx?pageURL=**http://someothersite/someotherpage.aspx?param1=value&source=http://anotheronesite/anotherpage**

I need to get the pageURL value as the one in the bold letters. But i'm getting

```
http://someothersite/someotherpage.aspx?param1=value
```

and i'm not getting the source param. I'm using the following JavaScript function -

```
  function getParameterByName( name )
  {
     name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
     var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
     var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
     var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
     if( results == null )
       return "";
     else
       return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
  }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where do you get the name/URL from?

Comment: I set in the code behind - C#.

Comment: I want everything pageURL. It is not going to change. Can i do it? A specific function taking pageURL as parameter is fine.

Comment: @NLV: I have no clue about `C#` but maybe this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380617/request-url-parameter Anyway, you have to encode the `&` so that it is not recognized as parameter of the "base URL".

Comment: If i HTML encode & i'm getting it as &amp. So?

Comment: @NLV: HTML encoding != URL encoding: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: Okie, so i should URL encode it. Not HTML encode. Got it. Thanks.

Comment: @Felix Can you post it as an answer? I would like to mark it as an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) to encode the parameter. Otherwise `&` is treated as *reserved character* and belongs to the "base URL".

Answer (score 0):

have u considered <strike>html</strike> url encoding the pageURL parameter?

this would greatly simplify your task

Comment: Okie, can you explain how it would help me?

Comment: No clues. Getting stuck in the same issue. Any ideas?

Comment: easy...everything after the first "=" in your name is your parameter.
just decode it back and you got yourself an url.

Comment: or to say it plain:
your script should work given the pageURL thingy is encoded.
just don't forget to encode it back.

jquery has htmlEncode and htmlDecode ;)

Comment: Okie when i encode it just & is replaced by &amp. Nothing else. So still & is preceeding the source link and it is not fetched by that JS function.

Comment: @NLV: This is HTML encoding, you need URL or percentage encoding.